# Adding property in Entity Framework T4 Template

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to add a property in the model classes that are generated by the Entity Framework. For this reason, I edited the T4 template (.tt file) and added the extra property in there.

As a result, each time I run a LINQ query against the database, I am getting `null` instead of the result I'm expecting. Without the extra property, it works fine.

I'm thinking this is a problem that EF is finding when attempting to map a database row against the model class. I tried adorning the extra property with the `[NotMapped]` attribute, but it made no difference.

Any idea what may the problem?

Comment: You added this in the .tt ? Do you mean you wanna add that property to all your entities ? How do one of your generated class look like ?

Comment: Yup, you understood right. The generated classes look like they normally would, just that they have this additional property I'm adding.

Comment: If you showed one of the entities and a sample of a query that works without the extra property, and not with it, we could be of some help...

Answer (score 0):

I made a small test project doing the same thing (adding a property to all entities by modifying the T4 template), and it worked just fine.

Turns out that in the actual project where I was trying to implement this, some code I added in the template was causing a NullReferenceException that wasn't bubbling up to the UI - I only managed to catch it by turning on first chance exceptions.